# Reading Android style information at runtime

Tags: android

I'm trying to retrieve Android style values at runtime, so I can apply them within a custom component. [(Passing a style ID as the 3rd parameter to an embedded View's constructor doesn't seem to work.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237752/android-set-textview-style-at-runtime) I've found `Context. obtainStyledAttributes(int, int[])`, but this seems to mysteriously fail to retrieve specific attributes that I know are set in the style. (That is, when the `int[]` of `android.R.attr.*` values contains a mix of attributes that are specified in the style and attributes that are **not** specified in the style, the `TypedArray` will have a value (*i.e.* `TypedArray. hasValue(int)`) for some, but not all, of the attributes that are specified in the style.)

I've also found `Resources. obtainTypedArray(int)`, and it seems to always have all the values in the style - but it seems very hard to use. The issue is that the values don't seem to specify which attribute they are for - they simply appear in the order that the attributes appear in the `<style>` resource.

- Even in the special case where I know which style I'm examining, I
  can't make assumptions about the order of the attributes: someone may
  come along and sort them alphabetically, or functionally, or
  randomly.
- In the more general case where I need to handle whichever
  style resource the user may have specified, I need to probe by
  `android.R.attr.*` value.

So, my question: **Is there any way to find which attributes, in which order, a style contains?**

I can call `Resources. getIntArray( styleId )`, but this does *not* give me an `int[]` of `android.R.attr.*` values!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why `Context. obtainStyledAttributes(int, int[])`, kept "mysteriously fail[ing]": the [int[] needs to be sorted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675709/getting-style-attributes-dynamically).